# Changing Object.toString() dynamically in Groovy has no effect when calling Integer.toString()

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I injected overridden method `toString` into `Object.metaClass`：

```
Object.metaClass.toString ={
   System.out.println("the string is $delegate")
}
```

and I thought that following code will execute this method:

```
1500.toString()
```

But it didn't not,nothing was printed to the console. That is what exactly confuses me: if something goes bad, then an error is to throw out; if `Object.metaClass.toString` is found and invoked, then the message will turn up, but why it is not working? What happened inside?

Comment: try `Object.metaClass.toString={->...}`

Comment: well, there's no change at all....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is correct, because `java.lang.Integer` overrides `Object.toString()` with its own implementation. If your assumption was correct then it would mean that you can break overridden method by forcing to use an implementation from parent class.

Consider following Groovy script:

```
Object.metaClass.toString = {
    System.out.println("the string is $delegate")
}

class GroovyClassWithNoToString {}

class GroovyClassWithToString {
    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "aaaa"
    }
}

new GroovyClassWithNoToString().toString()

new GroovyClassWithToString().toString()

1500.toString()

Runtime.runtime.toString()
```

When you run it you will see something like:

```
the string is GroovyClassWithNoToString@3a93b025
the string is java.lang.Runtime@128d2484
```

You can see that `GroovyClassWithNoToString.toString()`  called `Object.toString()` method and its modified version, also `Runtime.toString()` calls `Object.toString()` - I picked this class as an example of pure Java class that does not override `toString()` method.

As you can see overriding `toString()` method from `Object` level makes sense for classes that base on `Object.toString()` implementation. Classes that provide their own implementation of `toString()` wont use your dynamically modified method. It also explains why following code works:

```
Object.metaClass.printMessage = {
    System.out.println("Hello!")
}

1500.printMessage()
```

In this example we are adding a new method called `printMessage()` to `Object` class and all classes that don't override this method will use this dynamic method we just created. `Integer` class does not have method like that one so it's gonna print out:

```
Hello!
```

as expected.

Also keep in mind that `toString()` should return a `String` and it's better to not print anything to output inside this method - you can end up with nasty `StackOverflowError` caused by circular calls to `toString()` method.

### UPDATE: How `toString()` method is being picked by Groovy runtime?

Let me show you under the hood what happens when we call following script:

```
Object.metaClass.toString = {
    System.out.println("Hello!")
}

1500.toString()
```

and let's see what does Groovy during the runtime. Groovy uses Meta Object Protocol (MOP) to e.g. invoke any method called in a Groovy code. In short, when you call any Java or Groovy method it uses MOP as an intermediate layer to find an execution plan for a method - call it directly or use e.g. a method that was injected dynamically.

In our case we use plain Java class - `Integer`. In this case Groovy will create an instance of [`PojoMetaMethodSite`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/PojoMetaMethodSite.java#L40) class to meta class implementation for Java class - an `Integer`. Every meta method is executed using one of the Groovy `groovy.lang.MetaClass` implementation. In this case `groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl` is being used. One of the last methods that picks a method to execute is [`MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCachingInternal(Class sender, CallSite site, Class [] params)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L1312). If you put a breakpoint in the beginning of this method and run a script with a debugger, you will see that this method is executed with following parameters:

[image]

In line 1331 you can see that helper method called `chooseMethod(e.name, methods, params)` is being used:

```
cacheEntry = new MetaMethodIndex.CacheEntry (params, (MetaMethod) chooseMethod(e.name, methods, params));
```

This method is responsible for picking the right method to execute when we try to invoke `toString()` on `Integer` object. Let's get there and see what happens. Here is what this method implementation looks like:

```
/**
 * Chooses the correct method to use from a list of methods which match by
 * name.
 *
 * @param methodOrList   the possible methods to choose from
 * @param arguments
 */
protected Object chooseMethod(String methodName, Object methodOrList, Class[] arguments) {
    Object method = chooseMethodInternal(methodName, methodOrList, arguments);
    if (method instanceof GeneratedMetaMethod.Proxy)
        return ((GeneratedMetaMethod.Proxy)method).proxy ();
    return method;
}
```

> *Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L3158*

Now let's see what parameters are received when we call our script:

[image]

What is most interesting in our case is the first element of `methodOrList.data`. It's a method object of:

```
public java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString()
```

which is the method `toString()` that `Integer` class overrides from its parent class. Groovy runtime picks this method, because it is the most accurate from the runtimes point of view - it is the most specific method for `Integer` class provided. If there is no `toString()` method overridden at the class level (e.g. `Runtime` class example I mentioned earlier) then the best candidate for invoking `toString()` method is a `ClosureMetaMethod` provided by us in `Object.metaClass.toString = ...`. I hope it gives you a better understanding of what happens under the hood.

Comment: @Kylin.this `Integer.toString()` returns a `String` representation of `Integer` value - this is what this method suppose to do. `Object` is a parent class for `Integer`, `Object.metaClass.toString = {}` changes this method on a `Object` class level and `Integer` overrides `toString()` to provide its own implementation. That's why when you do `Integer.metaClass.toString = {}` you replace `toString()` method on a `Integer` class level and it works for it. Also please keep in mind that `toString()` should only return a String and it should not cause any side effects (like printing to console).

Comment: @Kylin.this I've updated an answer with more detailed explanation of what happens under the hood of Groovy runtime. Hope it gives you a better understanding how Groovy picks the best method candidate.

Comment: Do you mean that  it is `toString` implemented by `Integer`. not `Object.metaClass.toString`,that is invoked when executing `1500.toString()`? Then it seemingly makes sense that `1500.toString()` must print `1500` to Console whatever I do on `Object.metaClass.toString`  in that the latter has no effect on the former, doesn't it?

Comment: In fact, it generates `1500` on the screen if I define `Object.metaClass.toString={ "the string is $delegate" }` and execute `println 1500.toString()`. Maybe it's `println` in the body that causes the side effects of nothing output.....

Comment: `toString()` never prints anything to console, it always returns a `String` representation of an object. In this case `1500.toString() == '1500'`.  When you do `println 1500.toString()` you pass a value `'1500'` to println method and it displays String `'1500`' to console as `1500`. Replacing `Object.toString()` has no effects for `Integer` class because `Integer` overrides `toString()` and this overridden method has highest priority in Groovy runtime. You can replace it only by replacing `Integer.metaClass.toString = ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very kind of you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can override the Object.toString() that way.

But this works:

```
Integer.metaClass.toString = { ->
   System.out.println("the string is $delegate")
}
```

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5077208682987520

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Right, I know Integer.metaClass.toString works fine. But I just wonder why nothing is printed when I call 1500.toString()? In fact,if I define Object.metaClass.printMessage={out.println("the string is $delegate")},then 1500.printMessage() does print the message. Why toString not?

Comment: as I said, I don't think Object.toString can be overridden that at the Object level.

Comment: Sorry, but wait a minute. Provided that we cannot override toString at the Object level, what if it's at subclass level? In fact, it still can't work if I replace `Object` with `Number`,that is,`Number.metaClass.toString={...}`.It seems that **only** Integer is Ok.

Comment: But now there is another problem that how I design the code effectively if I prefer to make all instances of any class match the `toString` I define,that is, `1500.toString()`,`"msg".toString()`,`3.14D.toString()` and so on, all of which are gonna print message of the same format. It is of course nightmare to define `Integer.metaClass.toString`,`String.metaClass.toString`, `Doble.metaClass.toString`.....   isn't it?

Comment: Number is abstract, try metaClass on concrete subclasses, it should work. By the way, toString() MUST return String.